# forever start automatic.js error

Tags: node.js, git, screen, openshift, forever

so i wanted to make the app running on openshift

i made an application  and added the bitbucket url
(https://bitbucket.org/srabouin/backpack.tf-automatic)

its used to sell ingame items

so i open putty and do: cd app-root/runtime/repo/
then i type: node automatic.js
then it starts, but when i close putty, the app closes too...

its not made for openshift, so i saw maby you needed to edit the package.json file or something.

1) i would like to know what to change, or if you could change it for me

2) i use filezilla now to edit files and i think its working

i tryed to do this https://blog.openshift.com/run-your-nodejs-projects-on-openshift-in-two-simple-steps/

Could someone help me with forever?
i did: npm forever install
then: forever start automatic.js

```
    [trading-kurryworst003.rhcloud.com repo]\> forever start automatic.js
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: automatic.js
fs.js:549
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/lib/openshift/56d88d2e0c1e661d250000a9/.forever/_pTz.log'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
    at Object.forever.startDaemon (/var/lib/openshift/56d88d2e0c1e661d250000a9/io-js/bin/iojs/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever.js:460:14)
    at /var/lib/openshift/56d88d2e0c1e661d250000a9/io-js/bin/iojs/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever/cli.js:315:15
    at /var/lib/openshift/56d88d2e0c1e661d250000a9/io-js/bin/iojs/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever/cli.js:161:5
    at /var/lib/openshift/56d88d2e0c1e661d250000a9/io-js/bin/iojs/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever.js:412:11
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
[trading-kurryworst003.rhcloud.com repo]\>
```

if i dont cd to app-root/runtime/repo

and i use `forever start automatic.js` i get:

```
[trading-kurryworst003.rhcloud.com 56d88d2e0c1e661d250000a9]\> forever start automatic.js
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: automatic.js
error:   Cannot start forever
error:   script /var/lib/openshift/56d88d2e0c1e661d250000a9/automatic.js does not exist.
```

also tryed screen but doesnt work

Comment: When you close putty, you're ending your session, and that ends all processes that you started in that session. You need to daemonize the process, e.g. using [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever).

You probably don't have permission to push, but you haven't told us what the actual error is, so we can't help you.

Comment: have you seen this: https://developers.openshift.com/languages/nodejs/getting-started.html

Comment: @jarchuleta i seen that and i think i just need to update the package.json file

Comment: @user1431317 i dont think my forever works